# How to Flatten a JSON in 2 dimensions, can only flat in 1 dimension

Tags: python, json, flatten

We are trying to flatten a json in 2 dimensions, but we can only flatten in one dimension with the following function, this function returns the json in 2 dimension, but we want an array of json that you can make a dataframe of several rows(2 dimensions)

```
import json
from itertools import chain, starmap

def flatten_json(dictionary):
    def unpack(parent_key, parent_value, sep="_"):
        if isinstance(parent_value, dict):
            for key, value in parent_value.items():
                temp1 = parent_key + sep + key
                yield temp1, value
        elif isinstance(parent_value, list):
            i = 0
            for value in parent_value:
                temp2 = parent_key + sep + str(i)
                i += 1
                yield temp2, value
        else:
            yield parent_key, parent_value
    while True:
        dictionary = dict(chain.from_iterable(starmap(unpack, dictionary.items())))
        if not any(isinstance(value, dict) for value in dictionary.values()) and \
                not any(isinstance(value, list) for value in dictionary.values()):
            break
    return dictionary

j=json.loads('{"id":{"oid":"XXXXX"},"class":"YYYYY","version":"1","array": [{"key1" :  "value1"}, {"key2" :  "value2"}, {"key3" :  "value3"}, {"key4" :  "value4"}],"name":"GVASDAD","code":"V","level":6,"value":"0"}')


print(flatten_json(j))

Out[11]: 
{'id_oid': 'XXXXX',
 'class': 'YYYYY',
 'version': '1',
 'array_0_key1': 'value1',
 'array_1_key2': 'value2',
 'array_2_key3': 'value3',
 'array_3_key4': 'value4',
 'name': 'GVASDAD',
 'code': 'V',
 'level': 6,
 'value': '0'}
```

What I want to get is an array of json in the following way:

```
[{'id_oid': 'XXXXX',
'class': 'YYYYY',
'version': '1',
'array': 'value1',
'name': 'GVASDAD',
'code': 'V',
'level': 6,
'value': '0'},
{'id_oid': 'XXXXX',
'class': 'YYYYY',
'version': '1',
'array': 'value2',
'name': 'GVASDAD',
'code': 'V',
'level': 6,
'value': '0'},
{'id_oid': 'XXXXX',
'class': 'YYYYY',
'version': '1',
'array': 'value3',
'name': 'GVASDAD',
'code': 'V',
'level': 6,
'value': '0'},
{'id_oid': 'XXXXX',
'class': 'YYYYY',
'version': '1',
'array': 'value4',
'name': 'GVASDAD',
'code': 'V',
'level': 6,
'value': '0'}]
```

Any suggestion will help,

Thanks in advance to everybody!

Comment: Can we get a sample input?

Comment: Yes, you got the example in the code, the varible j contains the json that is going to be flatten, the output I got and the output I wish

Comment: What if there is more than one key-value pair in `{"key1" :  "value1"}`? And, does the key matter -- it is absent from the example output?

Comment: if there is one more level inside the array, as you say, inside the array: {"key1" : ["k1":"value1" , "k2":"value2"]} I would like to vertically flat this level as: {"key1_k1" : "value1","key1_k2":"value2 }